# Symlinked Dockerfile for environments

Tags: docker, production-environment, docker-compose

I'm trying to find an elegant way to split/maintain my docker configurations for my environments.

Here is my current directory tree:

```
docker-compose.yml
docker-production.yml
dev/
    web/
        Dockerfile
        nginx.conf
        ...
    app/
        Dockerfile
    db/
        Dockerfile
prod/
    web/
        Dockerfile
    app/
        Dockerfile
    db/
        Dockerfile
```

As you can see, my services config are each contained into a subdirectory of each environment.

My `docker-compose.yml` is based on `dev/` and `docker-production.yml` extends it and loads `prod/`

For an easier maintainability, I'm trying to use symlinks on the `prod` resources pointing to inherited files from `dev` depending on whether I'll need to change them or not. This would allow me to symlink an entire service directory or only certain files on it.

```
prod/
    web/
        Dockerfile -> ../../dev/web/Dockerfile
        nginx.conf
    app/ -> ../dev/app
    db/ -> ../dev/db
```

All seems to work fine but for the symlinked Dockerfiles:

> Building web
>   ERROR: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

2 questions:

- Does my technique seem ok to you or do you see any caveat/improvement ?
- How can I make docker accept symlinked Dockerfiles ?

Comment: Are you using boot2docker? symlink are not supported there.

Comment: That must be it. I'll have to find another solution for my environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, using boot2docker means symlink are not supported.

Seeing `Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile` is expected, especially if the symlink was created on the host (MacOs) and mounted by boot2docker (which won't interpret that symlink well)